# Porting an OOP application without inheritance to Erlang

Tags: oop, erlang

I have an application that extracts information from different data sources.   Since the extraction process is the same, except some steps, I have abstracted such different steps in corresponding classes, and I instantiate and pass each object to a generic search procedure.  I suppose that -- in Erlang -- I would use a record of functions instead of an object, right?

In case my description is not clear, here is some very simplified pseudo-code:

```
class Query1:

    def query_a(data):
        ...

    def query_b(data):
        ...


class Query2:

    def query_a(data):
        ...

    def query_b(data):
        ...


def extract_info(data,query):
    # Calls the methods `query_a` and `query_b` of `query`.
    # `query` can be either a `Query1` object or a `Query2` object.
```

Comment: Pass in the function you need to call instead of the object. What's the reasoning behind the porting, btw?

Comment: I can't pass just one function.  The pseudo-code is a simplification.  The extraction function is complex, and it needs to perform different queries in different spots.  I would port this small application as a chance to learn some more Erlang.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have couple of options:

You can pass both `query_a` and `query_b` as anonymous functions.

```
extract_info(Data, QueryA, QueryB) ->
    A = QueryA(Data),
    B = QueryB(Data),
    ...

extract_info(Data, fun({A, _B} -> A end, fun {_A, B} -> B end).
```

If the query logic is complex, you can define modules `query_a` and `query_b` and pass single atom to extract info:

```
-module(query1).
-compile([export_all]).

query_a({A, _B}) ->
    A.
query_b({_A, B}) ->
    B.
```

`query2` module would be analogus.

```
-module(other_module).
...
extract_info(Data, Query) ->
    A = Query:query_a(Data),
    B = Query:query_b(Data)
    ...

extract_info(Data, query1).
```

If the query logic depends only on data source, you can use function clauses that pattern match on different types. Lets say, that your data are tuples. Type one is something like this `{A, B}`, and second type is something like this `{{data1, A}, {data2, B}}`

```
query_a({A, _B}) ->
    A;
query_a({{data1, A}, {data2, _B}}) ->
    A.

query_b({_A, B}) ->
    B;
query_b({{data1, _A}, {data2, B}}) ->
    B.

extract_info(Data) ->
    A = query_a(Data),
    B = query_b(Data).
```

If the data sources are similar, you can always tag the tuples with single atom like: `{data1, A, B}` and `{data2, A, B}`. The last option is the most idiomatic if the query logic depends only on data type. For different queries, you have to use one of the previous ones.

Comment: The queries are simple, but there are many of them; therefore passing them as arguments is not feasible.  My understanding is that I can use modules as arguments, instead of records. Is that correct?

Comment: Your last edit is clear: I can use modules instead of records (in this case, at least).  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, module name is an atom and you can store it in `Variable` and then call `Variable:module_function()`. Function clauses are more natural in Erlang, but choose what makes the code more readable.